# keep data in form fields when navigating back react native - react-navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-hook-form

I am new to react native and react navigation.

I have a button that opens the registration screen (using navigation) in the registration screen I have a form, I would like you to help me in knowing how I can do so that when a user gives you back and returns to the registration screen, the data of the form and thus not have to re-enter all the data.

I'm using:
react-native with expo
react-navigation v5 and react-hook-form

I really appreciate what you can help me with

Comment: you will need a state machine: eg: https://github.com/bluebill1049/little-state-machine

Comment: @Bill gracias por responder, lo que have little-state-machine lo podria también implementar con context de react o no ?